# ODE for y" + 3y' = 28 cosh 4x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have this Equation: $y" + 3y' = 28 cosh(4x)$

So far this is what I have:

$ m^2+3m = 0 $

$ m(m + 3) = 0 $

$ m_1 = 0; $

$ m_2 = -3 $

$ Y_h = C_1 e^0 + C_2 e^{-3x} $

$ Y_h = C_1 + C_2 e^{-3x} $

$ r(x) = 28 cosh(4x) $

$ Y_p = K cosh(4x) + M sinh(4x) $

$ Y_p' = -4K sinh(4x) + 4M cosh(4x) $

$ Y_p'' = -16K cosh(4x) - 16M sinh(4x) $

Im stuck here:

$ -16K cosh(4x) - 16M sinh(4x) - 12K sinh(4x) + 12M cosh(4x) = 28 cosh(4x) $

I can seperate $cos$ and $sin$ to get $M$ and $K$

Do I need to use identities here to eliminate either $sinh$ or $cosh$?

Comment: Or, apply the general method explained there http://math.stackexchange.com/q/780608/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your next step is just to equate coefficients.

$$12M-16K=28$$
$$-16M-12K=0$$

Comment: so i can just ignore the sin and cos? and get the m and k via addition

Comment: @RebTuble Ignoring what?  You have $(12M-16K)\cosh 4x-(16M+12K)\sinh 4x=28\cosh 4x+0\sinh 4x$

Comment: oh now i get it, thank you but can you tell me what the other guy meant buy in terms of exp? thank you will work on this now :)

Comment: @RebTuble Hyperbolic trig functions can be written in terms of exponential functions, but I don't see how that would help solve it in the manner you did.

Comment: i see thank you then :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: express $\cosh(4x)$ in terms of $\exp$.

EDIT: $\cosh(4x) = \dfrac{1}{2} e^{4x} + \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-4x}$.
When $r$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial, $a y'' + b y' + c y = e^{r x}$  has a solution $\dfrac{e^{rx}}{a r^2 + b r + c}$

Comment: more hint please :)

Comment: You can use the method of undetermined coefficients after expanding $\cosh{4x}$ in terms of $\exp$.